# Z into Isabelle

Tags: formal-languages, logic, isabelle

I am trying to input and prove Z specifications in Isabelle.

Say I have a vending machine specification written in the LaTeX format:

```
\begin{zed}
    price:\nat
    \end{zed}

\begin{schema}{VMSTATE}
    stock, takings: \nat
    \end{schema}

\begin{schema}{VM\_operation}
    \Delta VMSTATE \\
    cash\_tendered?, cash\_refunded!: \nat \\
    bars\_delivered! : \nat
    \end{schema}

\begin{schema}{exact\_cash}
    cash\_tendered?: \nat
    \where
    cash\_tendered? = price
    \end{schema}
```

I don't know if I should put the schema's as lemmas or functions?

This is what i have so far:

```
theory vendingmachine
imports
Main Fact "~~/src/HOL/Hoare/Hoare_Logic"

begin
type_synonym price = nat

type_synonym stock = nat

type_synonym takings = nat

type_synonym cash_tendered = nat

function exact_cash "(cash_tendered:nat)"
where
cash_tendered ≡ price;
end
```

The type synonyms work fine however when I get to the exact cash schema which I have translated as an exact_cash functions I keep getting errors.

So in summary I would just like to know how to input schema's into isabelle.

Comment: I think there are not many people here speaking both Isabelle and Z. So maybe you can explain the semantics of your Z specification?

Comment: It also seems you are conflating types and terms: `type_synonym price = nat` defines a type, later on you (try to) define the term `cash_tendered` to be equal to a value `price` (which you have not defined anywhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people developed [frameworks for Z-specifications in Isabelle/HOL](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/community/Projects#Z) ([other link](https://www.brucker.ch/projects/hol-z/)) a decade ago. (As far as I know, they are not maintained anymore – but maybe they can still be of some help to you.)

Usually, Z-specifications can be rewritten into TLA specifications quite easily. So, you could also try to use the actively maintained [HOL-TLA-session](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/library/HOL/HOL-TLA/index.html) of Isabelle.

But let's first stick with common Isabelle/HOL.

Encoding your Z-specification fragment in plain Isabelle/HOL would look something like:

```
theory VendingMachine
imports
  Main
begin

--"record datatype for the state variables"
record VMSTATE =
  stock :: nat
  takings :: nat

--"a vending machine is parameterized over a price constant"
locale VendingMachine =
fixes price :: nat
begin

definition VM_operation ::
  "VMSTATE ⇒ VMSTATE ⇒ nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat ⇒ bool"
where "VM_operation vmstate vmstate' cash_tendered cash_refunded bars_delivered ≡
  True" --"TODO: specify predicate"

definition exact_cash ::
  "nat ⇒ bool"
where "exact_cash cash_tendered ≡
  cash_tendered = price"

end

end
```

Notice that I dropped the distinction between in- and output variables. The Delta-variable `VMSTATE` in `VM_operation` is split into `vmstate` and `vmstate'`.

To really work with such a specification, you would need some more auxiliary definitions. For instance, the state space of the specification could then be defined as an inductive predicate like, e.g.:

```
inductive_set state_space :: "VMSTATE set"
where 
  Init: "⦇ stock = 10, takings = 0 ⦈ ∈ state_space"
    --"some initial state for the sake of a meaningful definition...."
| Step: "vmstate ∈ state_space
∧ (∃ cash_tendered cash_refunded bars_delivered .
   VM_operation vmstate vmstate' cash_tendered cash_refunded bars_delivered)
⟹ vmstate' ∈ state_space"
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you for that answer very detailed and exactly what I needed!

Comment: im trying to add the schema definition
definition
some_stock :: "nat ⇒ bool"
where
"some_stock stock = (stock > 0)"
but getting the error "Type unification failed: Clash of types "_ ⇒ _" and "nat"" what would be the typing of this definition?

Comment: You need to read the full hint, it includes: "Operand:   stock :: ??'a VMSTATE_scheme ⇒ nat"... The problem is that the name "stock" is already used for the record selector – so you must rename your variable in the definition.